# Replace NaN values and shift numeric entries to NaN places

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a bizarre dataframe as shown in the image below. I want to remove all NaN entries and shift the numeric entries to the left of the dataframe.

Each row has 1000 entries but 30 of them are numeric and rest is NaN.

The difficulty I am having is there is no synch between rows. For the first 6 rows, numeric entries are from columns 969 to 999. For the next 6 rows, numeric entries are from columns 968 to 998 and this sequence goes on for 56053 number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this correspond to your example ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3, np.nan], [np.nan, 4, 2]])
dg = pd.concat([row.dropna().reset_index(drop = True).to_frame().T
                for idx, row in df.iterrows()
                ], 
               axis = 0,
               )
```

or

```
dh = df.apply(lambda row : row.dropna().reset_index(drop = True), axis = 1)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Thank you. But this is shifting bottom row entries to upper rows. I want to keep only 30 entries in each row. The final output should have a dimension of 56053, 30. If it's possible then please share.